# How to page break crystal report on change in alphabet.

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a an access database with first name and company name. I have a a report that runs about 100 pages long. I would like to know is there a way i can page break and start a new letter of the comapny on a new page for e.g

```
----A----

Automobile company 1 
Auto company 2 

-----B------

Bike co 1 
Bike co 2
```

and so on...Currently the report shows all letters together and i hv to manually seperate them which is very tedious. 
Also adding a new column to the access database with the initial of the company name is not feasible.

Please let me know if there is any other way of doing this.

Thank yoU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula to calculate the letter grouping:

```
//{@first_letter}
Left({table.company_name}, 1)
```

Insert a group on this formula; ensure that it is G1.

Format the group's footer, then check the 'new page after' property.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I did not get the part 'Format the group footer'. I got to the screen where i see the option next page after, but it does a page break for each company name , i dont need that. I want it to page break only on a new letter, for eg it shows 8 companies continuously with letter A, as soon as there is a company with initial B, it should page break - just like you have in on a phone book / directory